# Replace Poster Image with Wordpress Featured Image, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I use Plyr video player inside my posts and I want poster image to be automatically the featured image.

I use the following JavaScript but it doesn't work!

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
const controls = [
    'play-large',
    'restart',
    'play',
    'progress',
    'current-time',
    'duration',
    'mute',
    'volume',
    'captions',
    'settings',
    'pip',
    'fullscreen'
];

const player = new Plyr('#player', { controls });
  
  // Expose
  window.player = player;

  // Bind event listener
  function on(selector, type, callback) {
    document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(type, callback, false);
  }
});
(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("post_plyr")[0].setAttribute("poster", "<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'full' );?>"); 
        })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.2/plyr.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mhdizmni.ir/plyr-style.css"/>

<div class="mhdizmni_plyr">
<video controls crossorigin playsinline poster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg" id="player" class="post_plyr">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="480">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="720">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
                <track kind="captions" label="Persian" srclang="fa" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt"
                    default>
                <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt">
            </video>
</div>
```

Though it doesn't work in that way, if I change `<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( null, 'full' );?>` to an image link, for example, `https://mhdizmni.ir/plyr/mhdizmniPlyrPoster.jpg`, it works (see it work below), but I need the dynamic version.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { 
const controls = [
    'play-large',
    'restart',
    'play',
    'progress',
    'current-time',
    'duration',
    'mute',
    'volume',
    'captions',
    'settings',
    'pip',
    'fullscreen'
];

const player = new Plyr('#player', { controls });
  
  // Expose
  window.player = player;

  // Bind event listener
  function on(selector, type, callback) {
    document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(type, callback, false);
  }
});
(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("post_plyr")[0].setAttribute("poster", "https://mhdizmni.ir/plyr/mhdizmniPlyrPoster.jpg"); 
        })();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.2/plyr.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mhdizmni.ir/plyr-style.css"/>

<div class="mhdizmni_plyr">
<video controls crossorigin playsinline poster="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.jpg" id="player" class="post_plyr">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="480">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="720">
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4" size="1080">
                <track kind="captions" label="Persian" srclang="fa" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt"
                    default>
                <track kind="captions" label="English" srclang="en" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-HD.en.vtt">
            </video>
</div>
```

any idea how to fix it?!!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML for for your video, so that we can see what is happening. If you could create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would really help!

Comment: It looks like it might not have access to the post data. Where is this code (e.g. in functions.php or a template file?) and how is it being called? Is it inside the loop?

Comment: actually I use an acf field for HTML, CSS and JS. it's not in the loop. check out this address please: https://mhdizmni.ir/uncategorized/2020/393-%db%8c%d8%b0%d8%b1%d9%87%da%a9%d8%a7%d9%86/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` outside of the loop, you must pass the post id into it (it on'y picks up the current post id *inside* the loop):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("post_plyr")[0]
        .setAttribute("poster", "<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'full' );?>");
```

There are a few different ways of getting the current post id, I've included some below so you can decide on which works best for you (e.g. you might already be using global `$post` for example, you might prefer to use that):

```
// Use the get_queried_object_id function
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();

// OR Access the global post
global $post; $post_id = echo $post->ID;

// OR access the current query
global $wp_query; $post_id = $wp_query ->post->ID;
```

Comment: soryy to bother you again, the thing is that i use elementor and i have no idea how to use php and js together in elementor. thank you for your time

Comment: @Mahdi That's why it is really important to include all the information we need in your question, so we can give you an answer that works for you :)  I've never used Elementor so I don't know how you would do it. Sorry.

Comment: sorry for the bothersome; i'm new to "stackoverflow" and ofcourse a novice in HTML, JS,... i appreciate the time you spared. will use the code in future projects ofcourse